# Unable to post to a html file using python 27 and gae

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am building a shopping cart application. I have the login, logout, and signup portions of the application working. When the user completes the signup portion of the application they are redirected to the when they are presented with a selection of items as denoted below:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Gigi's Catering Menu</h1>

<form method="post">
    <label>
        <div><h2>Large Gourmet Meat & Cheese Tray</h2></div>
        <p>
             Fresh Roast Sirloin Beef, Baked Ham, and
             Roasted Turkey with Swiss and
             American Cheese<br>
             Serves 20-25 people
        </p>
        Price would be $54.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Large Gourmet Meat & Cheese Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="54.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>GiGi's Signature Chicken Salad</h2></div>
        <h3>Mini Croissants Tray Sold by the Dozen</h3>
        Price would be per Dozen $26.99
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Chicken Salad Mini Croissants Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="26.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
        <h3>Chicken Salad Sold by the Pound</h3>
        Price would be per Pound $7.99
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Chicken Salad Sold by the Pound">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="7.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>Relish Tray</h2></div>
        <p>
            Carrot Sticks, Celery Sticks, Olives, and
            Butterchip Pickles Served with Ranch Veggie Dip<br>
            Serves 10-15 people
        </p>
        Price would be $19.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="4">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Relish Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>Fruit Tray</h2></div>
        <p>Strawberries, Grapes, Pineapple, Honey Dew, Cantaloupe, and
        Watermelon (when in season)<br>
        Serves 15-20 people
        </p>
        Price would be $39.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Fruit Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="39.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>Toasted Ravioli</h2></div>
        <p>Served with Marinara Sauce<br>
        Serves 15-20 people
        </p>
        Price would be $19.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="6">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Toasted Ravioli">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>3 Foot Party Sub</h2></div>
        <p>Fresh Roasted Sirloin Beef, Baked Ham, Hard
        Salami, Swiss Cheese, American Cheese, and
        Green Leaf Lettuce<br>
        Serves 10-15 people
        </p>
        Price would be $39.99 Each
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="7">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="3 Foot Party Sub">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="39.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>Wing Tray</h2></div>
        <p>You can have your Wing Tray as a Buffalo Wing or Wild Wing. You can
        provide further information in the bottom section of this menu.<br>
        Serves 15-20 people and costs about $19.99 Per Tray
        </p>
        Wing Tray - Select This: Buffalo Wing
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="8">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Buffalo Wing Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
        <br><br>
        Wing Tray - Select This: Wild Wing
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="9">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Wild Wing Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>GiGi's Fresh Made Potato Chips</h2></div>
        <p>Served with a French Onion Dip Tray<br>
        Serves 10-15 people
        </p>
        Price would be $16.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="10">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Potato Chips Served with French Onion Dip Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="16.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>GiGi's Mini Sweet rolls</h2></div>
        <ul>
            <li>Ham & Swiss Cheese</li>
            <li>Fresh Roasted Sirloin Beef & Cheddar Cheese</li>
            <li>Fresh Roasted Turkey & Provel Cheese</li>
            <li>$21.99 Per Dozen
        </ul>
        Price would be Ham and Swiss
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="11">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Sweet Rolls Ham and Swiss By The Dozen">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="21.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
        <br>
        Price would be Roast Beef and Cheddar Cheese
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="12">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Sweet Rolls Roast Beef and Cheddar Cheese By The Dozen">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="21.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
        <br>
        Price would be Roasted Turkey and Provel Cheese
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="13">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Sweet Rolls Roasted Turkey and Provel Cheese By The Dozen">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="21.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>GiGi's Brownie Tray</h2></div>
        <p>Serves 10-15 people</p>
        Price would be $19.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="14">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="GiGi's Brownie Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>Variety Wrap Platter</h2></div>
        <p>Our Variety Wrap Platters come with Chicken Caesar, Turkey Ranch, and
        Buffalo Chicken Tender w/Ranch
        </p>
        Price would be $25.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="15">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Variety Wrap Platter">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="25.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>Tea Sandwiches</h2></div>
        <p>GiGi's Signature Chicken Salad or Tuna Salad on Wheatberry Bread<br>
        Serves 10-15 people<br>
        $25.99 Per Tray</p>
        Price would be Chicken Salad
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="16">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Tea Sandwiches with Chicken Salad on Wheatberry Bread">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="25.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
        <br>
        Price would be Tuna Salad
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="17">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Tea Sandwiches with Tuna Salad on Wheatberry Bread">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="25.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><h2>GiGi's Cookie Tray</h2></div>
        <p>Our Cookie Trays come with Chocolate Chip and Sugar Cookies<br>
        Serves 10-20 people</p>
        Price would be $16.99 Per Tray
        <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="18">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Gigi's Cookie Tray">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="16.99">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
    </label>
    <br>
    <hr style="height:0px">
    <br>
    <label>
        <div><h1>GiGi's Lunch Boxes</h1></div>
        <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
        <li><h2>Choice of Meat:</h2></li>
            <ul style="list-style-type:square">
                 <li>Fresh Roasted Sirloin Beef</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="100">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Meat - Roast Beef">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Fresh Ham</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="101">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Meat - Ham">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Fresh Roasted Turkey</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="102">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Meat - Roasted Turkey">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Chicken Salad</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="103">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Chicken Salad">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Tuna Salad</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="104">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Tuna Salad">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
            </ul>
        <li><h2>Choice of Cheese:</h2></li>
            <ul style="list-style-type:square">
                 <li>Cheddar Cheese</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="110">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Cheese - Cheddar">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Swiss Cheese</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="111">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Cheese - Swiss">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Provolone Cheese</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="112">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Cheese - Provolone">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Pepper Jack Cheese</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="113">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Cheese - Pepper Jack">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
            </ul>
        <li><h2>Choice of Bread:</h2></li>
            <ul style="list-style-type:square">
                 <li>Wheatberry</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="120">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Bread - Wheatberry">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Hoagie</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="121">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Bread - Hoagie">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Pretzel</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="122">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Bread - Pretzel">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Croissant</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="123">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Bread - Croissant">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
            </ul>
        <li><h2>Choice of a Side Item:</h2></li>
            <ul style="list-style-type:square">
                 <li>Potato Salad</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="130">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Side - Potato Salad">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Pasta Salad</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="131">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Side - Pasta Salad">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Potato Chips</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="132">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Side - Potato Chips">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
            </ul>
        <li><h2>Choice of a Dessert:</h2></li>
            <ul style="list-style-type:square">
                 <li>Brownie</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="140">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Dessert - Brownie">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
                 <li>Cookie</li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"> Select this Item
                 <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="141">
                 <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Dessert - Cookie">
                 Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}">
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <p>All of our Lunch Box meals come with Lettuce & Tomato.</p>
        <p>A Whole Meal In a Box! For $9.49 Each</p>
    </label>
    <br>
    <hr style="height:0px">
    <br>
        <label>
        <div>Additional Comments and/or Special Requests</div>
        <textarea name="body">{{body}}</textarea>
        </label>
    <div class="error">{{ error }}</div>


    <input type="button" value="submit">
    <input type="reset">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The functions that handle the menu and shopping cart and other necessary functions will be listed below but for simplicity sake I will only post the mainpage, menu, and shopping cart functions below:

```
class MainPageHandler(Handler):
    def render_form(self):
        """ Render a page with what the customer has ordered """
        t = jinja_env.get_template("mainpage.html")
        response = t.render()
        self.response.out.write(response)

    def get(self):
        self.render_form()

class MenuHandler(Handler):
    """ This will be a function to allow the user to create their specific
    order from the selected items. """
    def render_form(self, unq_id="", product_name="", price="", qty="", body=""):
        """ Render the new post form with or without an error, based on parameters """
        t = jinja_env.get_template("menu.html")
        response = t.render(unq_id=unq_id, product_name=product_name, price=price, qty=qty, body=body)
        self.response.out.write(response)

    def get(self):
        self.render_form()

    def post(self):
        unq_id = self.request.get("unq_id")
        product_name = self.request.get("product_name")
        price = self.request.get("price")
        qty = self.request.get("qty")
        body = self.request.get("body")
        # create new temporary order object and store it in the database
        tmp_order = Tmp_Order(unq_id=unq_id,
                    product_name=product_name,
                    price=price,
                    qty=qty,
                    body=body)
        tmp_order.put()
        self.redirect('/cart')

class CartHandler(Handler):
    """ This will be a function to allow the user to see what they have ordered
    from their selections within the menu. """
    def update(self, item):
        if item.unq_id not in self.content:
            self.content.update({item.unq_id: item})
            return
        for k, v in self.content.get(item.unq_id).items():
            if k == 'unq_id':
                continue
            elif k == 'qty':
                total_qty = v.qty + item.qty
                if total_qty:
                    v.qty = total_qty
                    continue
                self.remove_item(k)
            else:
                v[k] = item[k]

    def get_total(self):
        return sum([v.price * v.qty for _, v in self.content.items()])

    def get_num_items(self):
        return sum([v.qty for _, v in self.content.items()])

    def remove_item(self, key):
        self.content.pop(key)

    def render_form(self, item_list=""):
        # render the page
        t = jinja_env.get_template("cart.html")
        response = t.render(item_list = item_list)
        self.response.out.write(response)

    def get(self):
        self.render_form()

    def post(self):
        self.redirect('/checkout', unq_id=unq_id, product_name=product_name, price=price, qty=qty, body=body)
```

I get to trace back information when running the application and I am still struggling with this. The information is written in Python 2.7, Google App Engine, and Jinja2 environment. Any and all help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the traceback - it'll help show where to look?

Comment: I went through my traceback and I get no errors on that end. I am sorry I couldn't be of further assistance.

Comment: Reconsider. Tracebacks can be informative in subtle ways.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, your form has `<form method="post">`.  Where is its `action=` directive?  What url is it supposed to hit?  And, do you have a url handler for that?  I imagine in your code that it should go to the `MenuHandler` handler.

Perhaps it should be:

```
<form method="post" action="/menu_handler">
```

And your url handling should include:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPageHandler),
                  ('/menu_handler', MenuHandler),
                  ('/cart_handler', CartHandler),
              ],
              debug=True)
```

Next, check the console in your browser, to see if there are any posting errors.  Add logging to your `MenuHandler` to make sure the post is getting there.

That's a good start.